# Why does asymptotic distribution of LRT not depend on specific functions used to express null set?

Tags: distributions, asymptotics, likelihood-ratio

For a [likelihood-ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) (LRT) statistic, $\Lambda(x)$, the asymptotic distribution of the statistic $-2 \log \Lambda(x)$ is a chi-squared distribution, which occurs only under certain regularity conditions. Here, we have two hypotheses for the unknown vector $\theta$:

1. $H_0: \theta \in \omega$ versus
2. $H_1: \theta \in \Omega \cap \omega^C$.

Here, $\Omega$ is the full parameter space, and $\omega$ is the restricted subspace for the null hypothesis. The subspace $\omega \subset \Omega$ is defined in terms of $q$ independent constraints of the form $g_1(\theta) = a_1, \ldots, g_q(\theta) = a_q$, where $0 < q \le p$ and $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_q$ are constants. The functions $g_1, \ldots, g_q$ must be continuously differentiable.

Why does the asymptotic distribution of $-2 \log \Lambda(x)$ not depend on what the functions $g_1, \ldots, g_q$ actually are as long as they are smooth and independent?

Comment: In your notation, what is $p$? The length of $\theta$?

Comment: p is the dimension of Ω. So ω is a (p-q) dimensional manifold, in p-dimensional space, defined by q independent constraints.